# Can Decrepefied heroes be attacked?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Can decrepefied heroes be attacked by **Frost arrows**, **Glaves of Wisdom** or other toggle based skills with *pure damage*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as these spells are Orbs which rely on their autoattack components.

However, heroes that are decrepified can CAST these abilities by doing so manually as if there are a spell. If the ability is on autocast, this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could attack with Pugna decrepified targets if you had any Orb effect in wc3 Dota, but don't know if you still can. In Dota2 you can't.